# Combining two arrays and sorting the arrays Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string, double

I am looking to do something along the lines of combining two arrays of different types.  Essentially I am trying to do something like this

```
var alphabet = [b,c,a,e,f,d]
var numbers = [2,3,1,5,6,4]
```

as you can see, the numbers and letters already correspond with each other in the list above, they are just out of place.

I would like it spit out the letters and numbers in order such as

```
[(a,1)(b,2)(c,3)(d,4)(e,5)(f,6)]
```

I would appreciate the help, Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [`zip`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/func/s:Fs3zipu0_Rxs12SequenceType_S_rFTxq__GVs12Zip2Sequencexq__) the two arrays, that gives you an array of tuples (pairs)
  `[(b, 2), (c, 3), ... ]`.
- Sort that array  of tuples with respect to the first component:

**Swift 2** code:

```
let result = zip(alphabet, numbers).sort { $0.0 < $1.0 }
print(result) // [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3), ("d", 4), ("e", 5), ("f", 6)]
```

For **Swift 3,** replace `sort` by `sorted`.